# How can I unit test a GDB pretty-printer written in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, gdb, pretty-print

I have written a pretty-printer using the GDB Python interface for a (C) struct that has a tendency to change between software releases. Since the format is fluctuating I have tried to make the printer dynamic enough to adapt and always try to print something useful instead of throwing a Python exception.

Right now there are two major formats that I need to support but there is likely to be a few more in the future. I would like to write some unit tests for the printer to avoid having to manually load coredumps from different releases to test it.

I thought that maybe I could serialize the gdb.Value from within a debugging session and load them in my unit tests but I wasn't able to do it (pickle didn't work with gdb.Value). The core-dumps are really large so storing them with the pretty-printer and script GDB for the tests is not an option.

How can I unit-test my pretty printer without keeping huge core-dumps around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I unit-test my pretty printer without keeping huge core-dumps around?

Keep small core dumps :-)

Let's assume you have `struct Foo` that you have a pretty printer for, and that keeps changing between releases.

Compile the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
   struct Foo f;
   // initialize f with some values
   abort();
}
```

Compile and run this program, store it and the resulting core as `foo-v2` and `foo-v2.core` (assuming you are now on version 2 of the `struct Foo`). The core should be quite small.

Now checkout `foo.h` that corresponds to version 1 of `struct Foo` from your revision control system (you *do* use a revision control system, right?). Rebuild and re-run the program, store it as `foo-v1` and `foo-v1.core`.

Now, with every release, you just have to rebuild/rerun above program, and compare output of GDB pretty printer with expected result. If it still works ok, you are done. If not, `struct Foo` must have changed, and you need to update your pretty printer.

Save the new binary and core as `foo-v3` and `foo-v3.core`, update the pretty printer, then test it against all `foo-vN` and `foo-vN.core` pairs (for the test itself, use GDB unittesting framework that comes with GDB sources).

Comment: It's a good idea that I am considering. Preferably I would like to avoid having dependencies outside of Python though.

Comment: @DavidHolm Which dependency would you like to eliminate? I don't believe it's possible to eliminate the need to store foo-vN and foo-VN.core (but maybe you can just regenerate them as needed). Eliminating dependency on GDB testing framework is easy *if* the output of your pretty printer can be compared against "golden" output.

Comment: The dependency on GDB. Right now GDB 7 is not the officially supported version on our product so I am using my own GDB. Some people are using my build, others have their own, so I would prefer it if the test code was independent of whatever version of GDB it will find in the path.

Comment: @DavidHolm I don't quite understand: if you want your test to use a specific build of GDB, why can't you hard-code `/path/to/specific/build/of/gdb` into the test?

Comment: I can certainly do that and I guess I will have to. It's just that I would have preferred if the implementation was a bit more 'portable'. ^^